# Mapbox find annotation on the map after long press gesture

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapbox

I'm new on iOS development and mapbox, so sorry if question sounds to stupid but I can't find it anywhere answer to it. 
I have a map and annotations on it. I want to show some other info when user touches and hold on the annotation (long press gesture). I got long press gesture to work, but have found the way to find annotation which is touched, or at least index of it. So far I have it like this:

```
class eventsMapController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

    // Set the map's bounds to Oslo 59.920269,10.71167
    //let bounds = MGLCoordinateBounds(sw: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.925861, longitude: 10.712185),
                                //     ne: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.889798, longitude: 10.794754))        
    view.addSubview(mapView)

    // Set the map view‘s delegate property
    mapView.delegate = self

    let myGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(eventsMapController.testLongGesture))
    myGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.8
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(myGesture) 
}
func testLongGesture(long: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if long.state == .Began{ 
        print("begin", long)
    }
}
}
```

I'm adding annotations like this

```
let pointAnotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        pointAnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(event.lat, event.lng)
        pointAnotation.title = name
        pointAnotation.subtitle = headline
self.mapView.addAnnotation(pointAnotation)
```

Please help me someone, I used many hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

I think the first thing I'd try is implementing the delegate method `mapView(_:didSelectAnnotation:)`. I'm not sure if it will be called when a long press happens, but if so it'd make things relatively simple by telling you which annotation to use.

If not, you'll probably need to do something like:

1. Find out the map coordinate that corresponds to the long press location. Something like:

   ```
   let longPressPoint : CGPoint = long.locationInView(mapView)
   let longPressCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(longPressPoint, toCoordinateFromView:mapView)
   ```

   That gives you a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` corresponding to the long press location.
2. Run through your annotations, comparing each one's coordinate to the long press coordinate to find one that's close to the long press. Keep in mind that the long press might not be on any annotation, so don't automatically select the closest one.